# How to match words in a string which contain at least one vowel (a,i,o,u,e) using regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

It seems straightforward task, but I could not solve. I am fresh at using **re** module

`string1 = 'www Cristian www Bale www'` --- Here is my test string.

`pattern1 = '([aıoueəiöü])'` --- Pattern

```
import re

string1 = 'www Cristian Bale www'

pattern1 = '([aıoueəiöü])'

result = re.findall(pattern1, string1)

print(result)
```

It results just vowels which words have: `['i', 'i', 'a', 'a', 'e']`

My expected output is actually, these words: `"Cristian Bale"`.
How can I return these?

Comment: What is the desired result for 'Test-www www Cristian Bale www Test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
string1 = 'www Cristian Bale www'
pattern1 = r'\b[^\Waıoueəiöü]*[aıoueəiöü]\w*'
result = re.findall(pattern1, string1)
print(" ".join(result))
# => Cristian Bale
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/m0AHVa). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^\Waıoueəiöü]*` - any word char except the `aıoueəiöü` chars
- `[aıoueəiöü]` - a letter from the set
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars.

The `" ".join(result)` part creates a single string out of the extracted string list.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the *string* module offered a locale specific list of vowels?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string1 = 'www Cristian www Bale www'
vowels = re.findall(r'\w*[aeiou]\w*', string1)
print(' '.join(vowels))
```

OUTPUT

```
Cristian Bale
```